# minimizing & raising a window from a shell script

Tags: x11, window, xdotool

I am trying to run a script that will check internet speed on a linux machine with gui, bring the terminal window down and when the query is finished , the window will come up with the answer.
as for the time being- i can take the window down, but not up.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
    #xdotool set_window --name speedy
    #xdotool set_window --icon-name speedy
    speedtest-cli --simple

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    #xdotool windowactivate speedy
    xdotool windowfocus  #speedy
    xdotool key "F11"
    fi

    exec $SHELL
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`xdotool` needs to know the window ID for all its actions.
You correctly used `getactivewindow` to obtain the window for the `windowminimize` command, but you also need to do it for setting its name.  So put

```
xdotool getactivewindow set_window --name speedy
```

before the minimize line.

Then you can use `search` to find it for activating later.

```
xdotool search --name speedy windowactivate
```

See the manpage sections [Window stack](http://man.cx/xdotool#heading11) and [Command chaining](http://man.cx/xdotool#heading12) for an explanation of how this all works.

The whole script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# rename the window for finding it again later
xdotool getactivewindow set_window --name speedy
xdotool search --name speedy windowminimize

speedtest-cli --simple

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  xdotool search --name speedy windowactivate
  xdotool key "F11"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked for me. 
I also added exec $SHELL so the window wouldn't close after execution.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do it using xdotool, but this is how you can raise a window using wmctrl and switch to fullscreen mode with only one command:

```
#!/bin/sh
TITLE_OF_WINDOW_TO_BE_RAISED="Tor-Browser"
wmctrl -a $TITLE_OF_WINDOW_TO_BE_RAISED -b add,fullscreen
```

It also switches to the desktop containing the window and focuses it.
`-a` raises the window, `-b add,fullscreen` 'adds' the fullscreen property.

Comment: You should probably use `grep -F -e "$TITLE..."`, in case the title has any special characters in it.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Good catch, i edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JigglyNaga I just discovered that this can be done with wmctrl alone.

Comment: Thank you for the different approach, although I couldn't make it to work..

Answer (score 1):

To avoid renaming the window, save its identifier in a bash variable, that can be given back to `xdotool` for all future actions:

```
#!/bin/bash
WID=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
xdotool windowminimize $WID

speedtest-cli --simple

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  xdotool windowactivate $WID
  xdotool key "F11" $WID
fi
```